# Unable to have Elastic IP for EMR cluster

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I am running a datapipeline every once a day and the pipeline creates a temporary EMR to run the activities. The EMR connects to a Mysql database and the IPs for the master and core nodes need to be whitelisted in the DB.

Is it possible to assign static or elastic IPs to nodes on EMR so that I don't have to whitelist the node IPs manually everytime the EMR is created?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same situation and made a code for attaching the pre-obtained EIP to the master instance. But if you want to connect the AWS RDS, then you can simply allow the security group of EMR that is the best.

Below is what I used to fix the EIP for the master instance, not the others. In the case of the spark application with cluster mode, the master node has the driver session of the spark and only that is needed to be the whitelist.

```
#!/bin/bash
BOOL=`cat /emr/instance-controller/lib/info/instance.json | jq .isMaster`

if [ $BOOL == "true" ]
then
    ID=`/usr/bin/curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

    aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $ID --public-ip $1
fi
```

This script receives an argument that is the EIP what you want and I have put this code as a bootstrap action for the EMR. Be aware that the EMR should have the execution permission for `associate-address`.